# How to Get First Column Value on click in JavaFX TableView like JTable in swing?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, javafx-2, tableview

I want to get First column value as we can achieve in Jtable using swing. below is my code and image for jtable.

```
String Table_Clicked = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
```

[image: Jtable]

As you can see in image when i click to the **Name** column value **eight** it gives me first column value like **8**. But I select **Name Column**

So how to achieve this in JavaFX with TableView Componenet.

I get the selected Value from the TableView as you can see in image below with the code.

```
   tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
         if(tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) 
            {  
                TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableview.getSelectionModel();
                ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
                TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
                Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);
                System.out.println("Selected value IS :" + val);
            }

         }
     });
```

[image: TableView Of JavaFX]

So I want the same in tableview First column data as we can get in Jtable? so how to get that **NO** value.. as using my above code I get the value of selected Cell **that is eight** print in console.. but I want to get First Column Value.. Help me to go thorough Ahead.

Thanks..

**UPDATE FOR DATA FILLING CODE OF TABLEVIEW**

```
   PreparedStatement psd = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("SELECT No,name FROM FieldMaster");
    psd.execute();
    ResultSet rs = psd.getResultSet();

    for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;                
            namecol = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));
            namecol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>()
            {
            @Override
            public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) 
            {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
            }
        });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(namecol); 
            System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");


        }

            while(rs.next())
            {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++)
            {
                //Iterate Column
                row.add(rs.getString(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
            data.add(row);

        }
        tableview.setItems(data);
        conn.close();
```

Comment: Your code works for me.  I'm just wondering if `setCellSelectionEnabled(true)` and `setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE)` makes a difference.

Comment: @brian: what is output for your side? which code works for you?

Comment: When I click a cell, your listener will give me the value in the cell.  In you example that would be 8.  Notice you have a blue line highlighting all cells in the row.  If you use tableView.setCellSelectionEnabled(true) , only one cell will be selected.  The listener won't work if you don't click a new row, but it will give the value in the clicked cell.

Comment: @brian: no man I want the value of first column based on the selection of second column.. selected cell is also works for me!!

Comment: Ok, that's not too hard if you always want the value from the first column. `Object val = tableView.getColumns().get(0).getCellData(newVal);`

Comment: @brian : there is no method getcelldata()? work this line for you?

Comment: yes, you also use it in your sample code.  I just copied your code and changed from getting the column based on table position to getting the column based on it's index position in the table.  Just replace that whole line in your listener with the one I wrote.  You could delete all 3 previous lines.

Comment: @brian: check this line man `Object val = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);` I used with tablepostion not tableview.. both are different object :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution**

You can retrieve the relevant field by calling the getter on the model object corresponding to the selected row.

In the code below the `newValue.getId()` call is the key.

Without Java 8 lambdas:

```
final Label selected = new Label();
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener<IdentifiedName>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(
            ObservableValue<? extends IdentifiedName> observable, 
            IdentifiedName oldValue, 
            IdentifiedName newValue
        ) {
            if (newValue == null) {
                selected.setText("");
                return;
            }

            selected.setText("Selected Number: " + newValue.getId());
        }
    }
);
```

With Java 8 lambdas:

```
final Label selected = new Label();
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null) {
            selected.setText("");
            return;
        }

        selected.setText("Selected Number: " + newValue.getId());
    }
);
```

**Sample Code**

[image: selected]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewSample extends Application {

    private TableView<IdentifiedName> table = new TableView<>();
    private final ObservableList<IdentifiedName> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new IdentifiedName(3, "three"),
            new IdentifiedName(4, "four"),
            new IdentifiedName(7, "seven"),
            new IdentifiedName(8, "eight"),
            new IdentifiedName(9, "nineses")
        );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableColumn<IdentifiedName, Integer> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("No");
        idColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("id")
        );

        TableColumn<IdentifiedName, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<>("name")
        );

        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().setAll(idColumn, nameColumn);
        table.setPrefHeight(180);

        final Label selected = new Label();
        table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == null) {
                selected.setText("");
                return;
            }

            selected.setText("Selected Number: " + newValue.getId());
        });

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(table, selected);
        VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static class IdentifiedName {
        private final int    id;
        private final String name;

        private IdentifiedName(int id, String name) {
            this.id   = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

**Answers to Additional Questions**

> check my updated question so I can't use this?

So in your update you can see that the type of each row's data is `ObservableList<String>`, whereas in my answer the type is `IdentifiedName`.  To get the posted solution to work for your data type, the change is trivial.  The equivalent of `newValue.getId()` would be `newValue.get(0)`, to return the first item in your list for the selected row.

```
final Label selected = new Label();
table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
    (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue == null) {
            selected.setText("");
            return;
        }

        selected.setText("Selected Number: " + newValue.get(0));
    }
);
```

> or is it possible to use identifiedname class? then how?

Yes you could, but you would have to make extensive changes to your database fetching code to load the data created into an `IdentifiedName` class rather than an `ObservableList<String>` and doing so would lose the generic nature of your database loading code.

> I implement your code into my project I got ... `java.lang.ClassCastException:`

You need to setup the type of your Table and columns correctly for your data types, not the sample ones I provided for my use case.

Replace these types:

```
TableView<IdentifiedName>
TableColumn<IdentifiedName, Integer>
```

With these types:

```
TableView<ObservableList<String>>
TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String>
```

*Minor advice*

I advise taking a refresher by reading up on the [Java Generics Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).  Tables in JavaFX are pretty complicated in their use of generics, but using correct generics in your table code can make it easier to write (as long as you are using a good IDE which is good at guessing the generics when needed).

You also might want to provide an [minimal, complete, tested and readable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with future questions of this type (not all questions).  Construction of one could help you solve your issues quicker.  Also, ensuring your code has consistent indentation makes it easier to read.

Comment: @jewelsea: How to use identiedname class? because I fill the tableview dynamically from the database? so no getter setter available in my side?

Comment: @jewelsea: check my updated question so I can't use this? or is it possible to use identifiedname class? then how?

Comment: when I implement your code into my project I got the exception `Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper cannot be cast to myprojectpackage.CreateModeController$IdentifiedName`

Comment: @jewelsea [SSCCE is strictly refured on this forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214955/can-we-create-a-help-center-topic-that-outlines-what-a-sscce-mwe-means-for-sta) by endless and idiot*** rulles there, I'm disagree with results there too, now is here an [MCVE/MCTRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @mKorbel thx for info.  Meta and the MCVE are useful resources.  Updated answer to refer to MCVE rather than SSCCE.

Comment: @jewelsea: Thanks for your effort but this solution not work for me unfortunately so I can't accept as it's good for community or for future visitor.. but for your effort I will give you my +1 yesterday. Anyway Thanks Again!!

Answer (score 3):

You have to take a look at the underlying `ObservableList`. The code that works for me was:

```
tableView.getItems().get(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex())
```

In my test that returns a `Person` object (POJO i wrote) which has to contain a `get()` method.

Comment: it gives me output like `Selected value is  [8, Eight]`  but i want only `8`?

Comment: That is the toString() output of your `IdentifiedName` object. This class should have a `getNumber()` method.

`tableView.getItems().get(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getNumber()`

Comment: there is no method like getNumber()?

Comment: I just found the class in your code. Try `tableView.getItems().get(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()).getId()`.

Comment: there is no `getID()` method found in my class?? where do you get in my class?

Comment: What type does the `get()` method return? You posted your `IdentifiedTable` class!

Comment: sorry I can't get you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48670/discussion-between-lukas-leitinger-and-swing-fx2guru)

Comment: sorry man.. I don't have permission to enter into that room. as I am restricted from my place. so can you give me solution over here?

Comment: The code in my previous comment should return you an object of a IdentifiedName and you can call the functions you implemented.

Comment: so can you update your code? I don't know where to implement what you said?

Comment: I am sorry, I looked at jewelseas answer and I thought it was your code. My code should work if you use his implementation of the TableView.

Comment: Yeah I doubt earlier that may be you refering the code of jewelsea? but looking at your confidence I will keep sticking you for answer.. so do you have any idea how to get it? because jewelsea answer does not suit for my purpose..

Comment: I am not familiar with the classes you use to get your data. Could you look up what methods the object my code returns provides?

Comment: it gives me both colum data as I already told you earlier `[8, Eight]` ? but i want only `8`

Comment: As a String? Should be some other kind of object if I had to guess.

Answer (score 1):

I can get first column value using below code:

```
tableview.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observableValue, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                //Check whether item is selected and set value of selected item to Label
                if (tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) {
                    TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = tableview.getSelectionModel();
                    ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();

                    TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);


                    tablePosition.getTableView().getSelectionModel().getTableView().getId();
                    //gives you selected cell value..
                    Object GetSinglevalue = tablePosition.getTableColumn().getCellData(newValue);

                    getbothvalue = tableview.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();
                //gives you first column value..
                    Finalvaluetablerow = getbothvalue.toString().split(",")[0].substring(1);
                    System.out.println("The First column value of row.." + Finalvaluetablerow);
                }
            }
        });
```

Thanks..