# How can I find cell typing event in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've got a problem with JTable because recently I began work with Swing and I don't know this API well.

I would like to replace commas with dots in double's cell.

How to do it?

[image]

Comment: I created application with jTable and I would like to replace commas with double's

Comment: Look at picture in thread.
I would like to create event which would replace commas with dots aftert clicked enter or automatically.

Comment: Try this can help you 


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160899/value-change-listener-for-javafxs-textfield

Comment: It's work for JField object but I would like do it for column from JTable.

Comment: The cell. in Jtable is editable?

Comment: Yes, the cell is editable.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22088217/how-to-get-first-column-value-on-click-in-javafx-tableview-like-jtable-in-swing

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create event which would replace commas with dots aftert clicked enter or automatically.

The data in the cell of a table is displayed by using a renderer. You can use a custom renderer to format the data. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for basic information about renderers.

So you can create your own custom renderer ore you can check out [Table Format Renderer](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) which does most of the work for you. You just provide your custom `Format` object to the renderer class.